# How to calculate current month and previous month dynamically in sql?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-athena, presto

How to keep the amount for current month and previous month side by side so that the resultant after subtracting both is `320614.5204`?

Below is my input data  -

```
+----+------+----+-----+----+----+-----------+
|colA|period|colB|colC |colD|colE|amount     |
+----+------+----+-----+----+----+-----------+
|abc |202301|dt  |20110|1236|0000|200.9342749|
|abc |202301|dt  |20110|1200|0000|805086.453 |
|abc |202301|dt  |20110|1230|0000|1320.738729|
|abc |202301|dt  |20110|1057|0000|112563.2048|
|abc |202301|dt  |20110|0000|0000|481446.1162|
|abc |202301|dt  |20110|1185|0000|33143.72624|
|abc |202301|dt  |20110|1299|0000|179683.4546|
|abc |202301|dt  |20110|1208|0000|4645.649104|
|abc |202301|dt  |20110|8307|0000|12583.31342|
|abc |202301|dt  |20110|1903|0000|108461.0646|
|abc |202301|dt  |20110|1290|0000|1018387.778|
|abc |202301|dt  |20110|1711|0000|1367565.247|
|abc |202302|dt  |20110|1712|0000|23.19162437|
|abc |202302|dt  |20110|8158|0000|18382.71997|
|abc |202302|dt  |20110|1290|0000|828198.4983|
|abc |202302|dt  |20110|1903|0000|377226.3219|
|abc |202302|dt  |20110|1057|0000|51077.79188|
|abc |202302|dt  |20110|1299|0000|156910.4484|
|abc |202302|dt  |20110|0000|0000|513661.3896|
|abc |202302|dt  |20110|1185|0000|32263.95939|
|abc |202302|dt  |20110|1208|0000|733.999577 |
|abc |202302|dt  |20110|1236|0000|268.0203046|
|abc |202302|dt  |20110|8307|0000|11835.60702|
|abc |202302|dt  |20110|1711|0000|1311061.665|
|abc |202302|dt  |20110|1200|0000|1144058.608|
+----+------+----+-----+----+----+-----------+
```

This is only for one current month and one previous month. How to derive the same for the range of periods?
Having said that the current month and previous month will be rolling in such a way that present current month
and present previous month will loop over a range of periods defined.
For example, if my range of period is from 202212 till 202306 (Can be any number of months in this case it is 7 months) then below is how it'll be implemented -

```
1. Current and Previous month would be 202301 and 202212 respectively
2. Current and Previous month would be 202302 and 202301 respectively
3. Current and Previous month would be 202303 and 202302 respectively
4. Current and Previous month would be 202304 and 202303 respectively
5. Current and Previous month would be 202305 and 202304 respectively
6. Current and Previous month would be 202305 and 202304 respectively
7. Current and Previous month would be 202306 and 202305 respectively
...
...
...
So on and so forth for other use cases as well
```

I tried using the `lag` and `lead` function for the period 202302 and 202301 but it wasn't givng me the correct results -

```
Select 
    LOWER(colA) as colA, 
    "period", 
    LOWER(colB) as colB, 
    LOWER(colC) as colC, 
    LOWER(colD) as colD,
    LOWER(colE) as colE, 
    COALESCE(SUM(usdamount), 0) AS current_month, 
    LAG(COALESCE(SUM(usdamount), 0)) over(order by period ) as previous_month
from cte 
where trim(colC) = '20110' and lower(trim(colB)) = 'dt' and "period" between 202301 and  202302 
group by colA, period, colB, colC, colD, colE
```

Essentially my use is `SUM(CASE WHEN period = 202302 THEN amount END) - SUM(CASE WHEN period = 202301 THEN amount END)` should equate to `320614.5204`, and this needs be made dynamic as describe above. Also the grouping is needed because I need them in the output as well.

Comment: What is `202302` - an integer? A string? Looks like a string... which is a very poor way of storing what should be separate integer fields.

Comment: Period column is of type integer.

Comment: It basically shouldn't be either - it should be a date. Below I show how to parse it from a string to a date, but int to date is also straightforward

Answer (score 0):

Your `period` needs to not be a string in the database. With date math this is easy:

```sql
create table amounts(
  colA text not null,
  period int not null,
  colB text not null,
  colC int not null,
  colD int not null,
  colE int not null,
  amount real not null
);

insert into amounts(colA, period, colB, colC, colD, colE, amount) values
('abc', '202301', 'dt', 20110, 1236, 0000, 200.9342749),
('abc', '202301', 'dt', 20110, 1200, 0000, 805086.453 ),
('abc', '202301', 'dt', 20110, 1230, 0000, 1320.738729),
('abc', '202301', 'dt', 20110, 1057, 0000, 112563.2048),
('abc', '202301', 'dt', 20110, 0000, 0000, 481446.1162),
('abc', '202301', 'dt', 20110, 1185, 0000, 33143.72624),
('abc', '202301', 'dt', 20110, 1299, 0000, 179683.4546),
('abc', '202301', 'dt', 20110, 1208, 0000, 4645.649104),
('abc', '202301', 'dt', 20110, 8307, 0000, 12583.31342),
('abc', '202301', 'dt', 20110, 1903, 0000, 108461.0646),
('abc', '202301', 'dt', 20110, 1290, 0000, 1018387.778),
('abc', '202301', 'dt', 20110, 1711, 0000, 1367565.247),
('abc', '202302', 'dt', 20110, 1712, 0000, 23.19162437),
('abc', '202302', 'dt', 20110, 8158, 0000, 18382.71997),
('abc', '202302', 'dt', 20110, 1290, 0000, 828198.4983),
('abc', '202302', 'dt', 20110, 1903, 0000, 377226.3219),
('abc', '202302', 'dt', 20110, 1057, 0000, 51077.79188),
('abc', '202302', 'dt', 20110, 1299, 0000, 156910.4484),
('abc', '202302', 'dt', 20110, 0000, 0000, 513661.3896),
('abc', '202302', 'dt', 20110, 1185, 0000, 32263.95939),
('abc', '202302', 'dt', 20110, 1208, 0000, 733.999577 ),
('abc', '202302', 'dt', 20110, 1236, 0000, 268.0203046),
('abc', '202302', 'dt', 20110, 8307, 0000, 11835.60702),
('abc', '202302', 'dt', 20110, 1711, 0000, 1311061.665),
('abc', '202302', 'dt', 20110, 1200, 0000, 1144058.608);

with sane_dates as (
  select period,
         make_date(year => period/100, month=>period%100, day=>1) as period_start,
         sum(amount) as amount
  from amounts
  group by period
)
select amounts.*, differences.diff
from amounts
join (
  select second.period as period,
         second.amount - first.amount as diff
  from sane_dates as first
  join sane_dates as second on second.period_start = first.period_start + make_interval(months => 1)
) differences on differences.period = amounts.period;
```

```
cola    period  colb    colc    cold    cole    amount  diff
abc     202302  dt  20110   1712    0   23.191624   320614.25
abc     202302  dt  20110   8158    0   18382.72    320614.25
abc     202302  dt  20110   1290    0   828198.5    320614.25
abc     202302  dt  20110   1903    0   377226.3    320614.25
abc     202302  dt  20110   1057    0   51077.793   320614.25
abc     202302  dt  20110   1299    0   156910.45   320614.25
abc     202302  dt  20110   0   0   513661.38   320614.25
abc     202302  dt  20110   1185    0   32263.959   320614.25
abc     202302  dt  20110   1208    0   733.9996    320614.25
abc     202302  dt  20110   1236    0   268.0203    320614.25
abc     202302  dt  20110   8307    0   11835.607   320614.25
abc     202302  dt  20110   1711    0   1.3110616e+06   320614.25
abc     202302  dt  20110   1200    0   1.1440586e+06   320614.25
```

Comment: Will it work with integer type period column? Also I want other columns as well in the output.

Comment: Yes; you just need to either cast to a string before the `to_date()` call or construct a date from a floordiv-and-modulus.

Comment: The other columns cannot be in the output unless you're (much more) clear about what the output should actually look like; you'll either need a partition or you can't have them in a group

Comment: @djm see edit. This demonstrates an integral `period` and a join to the original table.

Comment: Can't we split the `diff` based upon `colD`? That way values in diff column is not repeated?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. You haven't described it in your question. My crystal ball seems to be malfunctioning today.

Comment: I have mentioned like I need all the columns as mentioned in the `group by` in the question

Comment: Also your conditions wouldn't work on `spark-sql` or `athena`. Could you please rephrase your answer?

Comment: Did you check on this?